# How should I design a game character class with a large number of attributes?

Tags: class, attributes

I am a student who is currently learning Java and trying to write a small text-based RPG game with it. The first problem I encountered in the design of the game is the 'character' class, which represents all the playable heroes and enemy characters, and is now implemented by myself as the following:

```
class RPGActor {

private String name;
private int HP; // hit points
private int MP; // mana
private int AP; // attack
private int DP; // defense

... // followed by tens of other attributes. 

public Actor(int actorID)
{
    ... // Reads all attributes from a file based on the 'actorID'.
}
public void printStatus()
{
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println("HP :" + HP); 
    System.out.println("MP :" + MP); 
    ... // And print all the attributes one by one.
}
public void setHP(int newHP)
{
    HP = newHP;
}
public int getHP()
{
    return HP;
}
public void setMP(...)
{
    ...
}
// And tens of accessors and mutators for each attribute
}
```

The problem I see with this design is that there are too many things that needs to be hand-coded: There are some 20-30 attributes in the class, and a separate accessor/mutator needs to be implemented for each of them. And the function for displaying the current status of the hero, printStatus, must output each attribute separately even though every line of output follows the exact same format. This makes the class definition tediously long.

Plus, if later I want to add one more attribute to the game, then I must remember to modify 'printStatus', and add a pair of accessor/mutator for it.

So my question is: is there a way to design the class so that I can use ONE pair of set/get functions to set all attributes. Something like:

```
public void set(String attribName, int attribVal)
{
...
}
```

and print the attributes iteratively like this:

```
public void printStatus()
{
    System.out.println(name);
    for (...)
        System.out.println(curAttribName + ": " + curAttribVal);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Reminds me of Zork somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you a solution, to set all attributes with one method, but you shouldn't use it, I'll tell you the reasons afterwards.

```
class RPGActor {
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String HP = "HP";
    private static final String MP = "MP";
    private static final String AP = "AP";
    private static final String DP = "DP";
    // ... followed by tens of other attributes. 

    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();    

    public RPGActor(int actorID) {
        this.attributes.put(NAME, nameFromFile);
        // ... Reads all attributes from a file based on the 'actorID'.
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object value) {
        this.attributes.put(attributeName, value);
    }

    public int getAttribute(String attributeName) {
        return this.attributes.get(attributeName);
    }
}
```

This has several disadvantages:

- no code-completion for setting specific attributes
- less readable
- ...

---

**BETTER:**

Although you are using classes and objects, this isn't very [object-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented#Fundamental_features_and_concepts). Especially you're violating the [encapsulation paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

You shouldn't set the HP explicitly from outside the class itself. Only in rare use cases that is needed. Instead you should think about what the actor really does: attacking, defending, casting spells.

Therefore it should look more like this:

```
class RPGActor {
    private String name;
    private int HP; // hit points
    private int MP; // mana
    private int AP; // attack
    private int DP; // defense
    // ... followed by tens of other attributes. 

    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();    

    public RPGActor(int actorID) {
        // ... Reads all attributes from a file based on the 'actorID'.
    }

    public void attacks(RPGActor defender) {
        defender.defend(this.getAttack());
    }

    public void defend(Attack attack) {
        switch (attack.getType()) {
            case PHYSICAL:
                // This actor is resistant against physical attacks.
                return;
            case MAGICAL:
                this.HP = this.HP - attack.getStrength();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void castSpell(Spell spell, Set<Target> targets) {
        // targets could be other actors, equipment or chickens dependent on the spell
        // ...
    }

}
```

With [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) or more advanced design patterns like the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) you can make each actor react differently on attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The reason it was designed that way is that, there is actually another class, called DungeonMaster, that handles all the attacking/defending/spellcasting events. When an attack occurs, for instance, DungeonMaster decides who the attacker/defender are and how much HP he should lose(the defender does not know why he loses HP). I believe your second solution is indeed a more elegant design. But can you please elaborate on why the original design violates encapsulation? I thought encapsulation means attributes are invisible to user, guaranteed by 'private'.

Comment: Your Dungeon Master is actually a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). It concentrates too much knowledge about attack, defense, spells, creatures, ... 
That the defender doesn't know why he loses HP is a misconception in my opionion, because the defender might have armor or resistance, therefore the HP loss is dependent on the individual creature and therefore should be handled by the defender (but it could also be designed differently, this isn't the only solution).

Comment: Encapsulation isn't as simple as just making attributes private, but it's a common understanding, which if fell for when I started programming, too. The encapsulation paradigm is about concentrating logic and attributes in one place and restricting access from outside as much as possible. In contrast making attribute HP private, but providing getters and setters to manipulate it without any restrictions, doesn't encapsulate the attribute or the logic, it's just another way to access it.

Comment: Another important aspect is maintainabilty. If you decide to change the way creatures defend themselves, I would assume that RPGActor has to be changed. But probably I have to change RPGActor and DungeonMaster. This isn't problem at the beginning, but as you add more features it becomes more confusing by and by. You should read about the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Law_of_Demeter). 
There are a lot of good books about object-oriented programming, but most of the paradigms are described on Wikipedia very well. Take your time to read through the important parts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It clarifies a lot of things. I haven't really learned any deep knowledge about design pattern in school yet, so that RPGActor/DungeonMaster design is the best thing I could come up with intuitively. I'll definitely take your advice and start reading more about what a good design pattern should look like. Again, thank you very much for your help!